# Why do excitations not exist in non-quantum fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, terminology

In my understanding, where the value of a quantum field [i.e. a field with discrete values] is 0 it is said to be in the ground state, and where it is not 0 it is said to be an excitation. Why do we not use the same convention with non-quantum fields [i.e. fields where any real value is possible]. My only guess is that it is very rare for a non-quantum field is to be at exactly 0, so the terminology has no practical use outside of quantum fields.

Comment: Quantum fields are not "fields with discrete values".

Comment: *"In my understanding, where the value of a quantum field [i.e. a field with discrete values] is 0 it is said to be in the ground state, and where it is not 0 it is said to be an excitation."* Every part of this sentence is wrong. Quantum fields do not have definite values, let alone discrete ones. For what an "excitation" of a quantum fields is, see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154391/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127141/50583 and their linked questions.