# Is the Young's modulus the same for compressive and tensile test?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain, structural-beam

I want to know the Young's modulus for a compressive test, but I have just a tensile test. Are they of the same value?

Answer (score 1):

For a linear isotropic Hookean material, the Young's modulus of elasticity is the same for compression and tension.

$E = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}$

where $E$ is the Young's modulus, $\sigma$ is the normal stress and $\epsilon$ is the normal strain.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence is derived [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408987/can-hookes-law-be-derived/408992#408992), for example. Briefly, any smooth energy minimum examined up close looks like a parabola, which is symmetric around the equilibrium point. A parabolic strain energy corresponds to a linear restoring force (corresponding to Hooke's Law) and a constant stiffness in both tension and compression.