# Hooke's law and atomic scale

Tags: classical-mechanics, atomic-physics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, approximations

Hooke's law is derived in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408987/can-hookes-law-be-derived) answer by Taylor expanding an energy potential with arbitrary functional form. This is dependent on the displacements involved being "small".

By considering the scale of atomic forces in, say, a spring, how do we see this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the atomic scale there are two forces of interest. One is simple Coulombic attraction, and the other is a more complicated repulsive force which includes the Pauli exclusion principle and other quantum mechanical effects.

The attractive force can be represented by the potential: $$E_A=\frac{z_1 z_2 e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0  r}=-\frac{A}{r}$$

The repulsive force can be approximately represented by the potential: $$E_R=\frac{B}{r^n}$$ where $B$ and $n$ are parameters that depend on the atoms involved and capture the behavior of the QM effects. Often $n\approx 8$

This function, $E(r)=E_A+E_R$ has a minimum at $$r_0=\left( \frac{nB}{A}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$$ and around that point the potential is $$E(r)=E(r_0+\delta r)=-B(n-1)\left(\frac{nB}{A}\right)^{-\frac{n}{n-1}} + A(n-1)\left(\frac{nB}{A}\right)^{-\frac{3}{n-1}} \delta r^2 + O(\delta r^3)$$

Note that this has the form of the potential for a spring with the spring constant being obtained from the second term.