# Can we prove the Hooke's law?

Tags: elasticity, approximations, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

I was learning about stress and strain and my text book suddenly mentions about this law so called hooke's law.
It states that
$$\text{stress}\propto \text{strain}$$
Or,
$$ \text{stress}=k \times  \text{strain}$$
Where $k$ is the constant of proportionality.
I have basic knowledge of strain and stress.

**My question:-**

How to prove the hooke's law?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Hooke's law be derived?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/408987/)

Answer (score 2):

Physical laws do not necessarily need to be proved mathematically, but are generalizations of the results of physical experiment. In other words a physical law is 'proven' not by math and logic, but experiment and observation.

It is possible to derive the results from other assumptions, and @Chemomechanics posted a [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408987/can-hookes-law-be-derived) to a good derivation. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) page also adds a significant amount of additional sources and reading material. This quote from the wikipedia page is relevant.

> "Hooke's law is only a first-order linear approximation to the real
> response of springs and other elastic bodies to applied forces. It
> must eventually fail once the forces exceed some limit, since no
> material can be compressed beyond a certain minimum size, or stretched
> beyond a maximum size, without some permanent deformation or change of
> state. Many materials will noticeably deviate from Hooke's law well
> before those elastic limits are reached."