# Why can some oscillations be modeled by Simple Harmonic Motion, while others cannot?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, non-linear-systems

For some oscillators an increase in the driving amplitude changes the period (frequency) of the oscillation, but the simple harmonic oscillator does not predict this type of behavior. Why?

Comment: Related: [Why is the harmonic oscillator so important?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159021/44126)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: At increased amplitude higher-order terms in the potential (quartic, etc.) become non-negligible.

Comment: Awesome, and how do those terms affect the period?

Comment: Well, that would depend on the higher order terms now, wouldn't it?

Comment: Fair enough, but are there any general examples of when the terms would shorten the period or lengthen it? Or a way to directly link period and amplitude?

Comment: Imagine a pendulum.  A pendulum is _not_ a simple harmonic oscillator.  I'm not a physicist, and I don't know what equation would accurately describe the motion of a pendulum, but whatever it is, it's going to have some terms that become more significant as amplitude increases, and it's going to have some that don't, and just by an amazing coincidence, the limit as amplitude approaches zero is going to look like an SHO.  Same goes for a mass and spring system where the spring does not actually obey Hooke's Law, but rather, some law that approaches Hooke's Law as displacement approaches zero.

Comment: see [Nonlinear spring $F=-kx^3$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331632)

Answer (score 1):

In general it's **nonlinearity** that leads to the type of behavior you describe.

Simple harmonic motion is usually modeled in terms of linear differential equations, but *real* physical systems tend to be nonlinear to some degree and sometimes the non-linearities can become large as a function of the amount of energy you put into the system.

As physicists or engineers we tend to force the nonlinear behavior into simple non-linear differential equations like the [Vander-Waals model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation), the [duffing oscillator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DuffingDifferentialEquation.html), but more often than not there is the [saturation nonlinearity](http://www.deu.edu.tr/userweb/zeki.kiral/NONLINEAR_CONTROL/Common_Nonlinearities_and_Describing_Functions.ppt) (systems can only hold so much energy before they literally break)

For linear systems if you excite the system with a pure frequency you expect to see the same frequency at the system output. If you double the amplitude you would expect to see a doubling of the output. But if you excite a system and see changes in frequency with changes in the amplitude of your excitation, or non-proportional changes in the amplitude, then the likelihood is there is a nonlinear behavior lurking within.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example of a [plane pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum) with bob mass $m$ and length $\ell$, where the potential energy of the pendulum bob is
$$
U = -mg\ell \cos\theta
$$
up to a constant.  For small angles $\theta\ll 1\rm\,radian$ this is approximately simple harmonic, because neglecting higher-order terms in the Taylor expansion
$$
\cos\theta = 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2!} + \frac{\theta^4}{4!} - \cdots
$$
gives a potential proportional to $\theta^2$, just like a spring.  However the full equation of motion for a plane pendulum,
$$
m\ell\ddot\theta = -mg\sin\theta
$$
is a [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation) version of a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation).  The exact solution [seems to involve](http://www.pgccphy.net/ref/nonlin-pendulum.pdf) the [Jacobian elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions).

There are an infinite number of ways an oscillator can be non-harmonic, so there isn't a *general* answer to your question as stated.