# Why is the potential always quadratic in nature?

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential, harmonic-oscillator

Quadratic potential is a good approximation for the minima of smooth functions. This is I think is the reason that simple harmonic motion is so common.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: It's the simplest polynomial with a stable minimum.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, there a lot of wonderful effects that arises when you go further with your approximation, not stopping at the quadratic term. Take a look, for instance, to the second harmonic generation or the electrooptic effects in nonlinear optics!

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159021/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the harmonic oscillator so important?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159021/)

Comment: In 3D, it is the only possible divergence-free force field originating from a pointlike monopol source.

Comment: @peterh Write an answer expanding on this and I will accept it

Comment: @Demosthene I think your answer is very good from the Occam's razor view, but I think the selecting only the polynomial functions is an arbitrary choice from the viewpoint of the question.

Comment: @veronika I can't, it is already held. I can vote to reopen it, and I do, but my vote will probably not enough. Also you can vote to reopen your own question, so we will need only 3 (unfortunately, probably there won't be, but we can try).

Comment: @veronika Furthermore, your question is about the potential of things in a linear force field (i.e. $F=c \cdot r$), my comment is about the force around pointlike charges. Thus my comment doesn't answer your question. But you can ask a new question about that why are there always $\frac{1}{x^2}$-like forces.

Comment: @peterh Of course, of course, but the question is about the quadratic *approximation* around minima. The Taylor series of most usual potentials (periodic functions, exponentials, power laws, etc.) will always be polynomial.