Are vibrating strings in string theory perpetual motion?
I have never learned string theory, so please forgive me if my question sounds naive or obvious, but I would like to know and I am most likely wrong.
As far as I know, strings vibrate in different modes and different modes correspond to different fields (electrons, photons etc) which is a fascinating idea. And to the best of my knowledge, these strings never stop vibrating as to continue being the fields that we know and love, i.e. my tasty fermionic coffee.
However, does that mean that these strings are perpetually in motion? I thought that violates the law of conservation of energy?
Taken from another perspective, since strings vibrate, i.e. fluctuate, would the Fluctuation-dissipation theorem apply here and eventually stop the vibration?

Why would this "oscillation" disturb you in string theory if the analogous picture of a particle as "excitation of a field" in QFT doesn't? See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/355487/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127141/50583 for discussion of the "oscillators" in QFT, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305760/50583 for the relation between "vibrating strings" and particles, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458329/50583 for general ontology of strings and spacetime

@ACuriousMind You make a good point, thank you for sharing those links. I guess the "oscillation" is not what it says it is, but it is a mathematical artifact that the physics seems to match the oscillatory equations but the physical nature of the system is not oscillatory.

What makes you believe that "the oscillation is not what it says it is"? Also, the fluctuation-dissipation theorem is completely irrelevant here as that is a theorem in statistical physics.

@ACuriousMind if you don't mind, if you could provide a quick summary of all that with those links in your answer, I think it would be beneficial for anyone coming to this post and seeing all the different ways you could answer this question. I would be glad to mark it as the correct answer so we can wrap up this question. Thanks.

@Prahar Don't worry about that, I just meant that when we say that the system is in "oscillation" it is just the math that makes it so, but not the physics, as the physics is much more complex than we can imagine. What I said was not a precise statement, I retract it.

You might as well ask whether Newton's first law violates conservation of energy.

@Prahar Not according to this comment https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761434/quantum-fluctuations-are-not-real-but-yet-they-can-create-observable-phenomena#comment1706676_761434. And this paper https://jamesowenweatherall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Sybil_de_Clark_April11.pdf which does a deep dive into fluctuation-dissipation and quantum effects.

The comment says, "There is a famous theorem called the fluctuation-dissipation theorem that links random phenomena in systems to observable dissipative behavior." The keyword here is random. The FD theorem is a statement about statistical phenomena. The stringy oscillations you are referring to here are NOT random in any way. It may lead to observations that are statistical in nature (which is the case for all quantum systems), but that is not what your question is about.

The electron in the ground state of the Bohr model orbits the proton forever. This is “perpetual motion”, but it doesn’t violate energy conservation.

Hi Tachyon.  I don't know string theory either, but I wanted to point out to you that perpetual motion does not violate the law of conservation of energy.  As Connor pointed out, Newton's first law also does not violate conservation of energy.  A "Perpetual Motion Machine" DOES violate conservation of energy.  This type of machine can do infinite WORK with no external energy source.

Regarding the dissipation,
in string theory, different vibrational modes of a fundamental string are interpreted as different types of particles.
The ground state refers to the lowest energy vibrational mode of the string. This would correspond to the most stable configuration of the particle.
For a particle to decay, it must transition to a lower energy state by releasing some energy (e.g., in the form of other particles).
If the particle is at its ground state, there are no lower-energy states available. Hence, there's nothing it can decay into, making it stable. If the particle is isolated, then it cannot decay nor dissipate energy.
I don't understand though, why you think a vibration that keeps its energy violates energy conservation.

Yes, thank you for answering. As @James pointed out in the comments under my question that I was confusing perpetual motion with "Perpetual Motion Machine" as they are 2 different concepts. And as others have pointed out, there are things that can be in perpetual motion but do not violate energy conservation. And thank for you teaching me why Muons and other heavy particles decay from a string theory point of view, very insightful.

Do not forget also, that there are perpetual motion machines of the second kind that do not violate conservation of energy, but only the second law.
